# Arrow function in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I just went through some react code, I am a bit confused about this arrow function.
I know drawer is the function name, open here is a parameter, what about () ? what does it use for? can someone explain it? Many thanks!

```
  drawer = open => () => {
    this.setState({
      test: open,
    });
  };
```

I can call this function by this.drawer(true)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called a [curried function](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/curry-and-function-composition-2c208d774983).

It is the equivalent of the following code :

```
  drawer = (open) => () => {
    this.setState({
      test: open,
    });
  };
```

This function needs to be called twice in order to be executed :

```
drawer('something')();
```

The first call : `drawer('something')` will return another function that you only have to call once with the `open` value already set up for you.

It is usually used to preconfigure callback passed to component props :

```
<DrawerOpener setOpen={this.drawer(true)}/>
```

Your component `DrawerOpener` can then call `props.setOpen()` to trigger an open event will not being able to chage the `open` variable of the function.

Answer (score 2):

You are actually declaring a function which returns another function. An old-school equivalent of your code would be:

```
drawer = function(open) {
  return function() {
    this.setState({
      test: open,
    });
  }
}
```

Note that if you use classic `function` instead of arrow functions, `this` won't reference your class instance without [binding](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind).

Answer (score 1):

What you're seeing here is called currying, where one arrow function returns another arrow function. So in your example, the first function has the parameter open, it then returns a function that then accesses the first one's parameter by creating a closure.

Here's some more examples: https://scotch.io/tutorials/closures-and-currying-in-javascript

From the link above there's a really good example that illustrates what's happening here and how it can be used:

```
let greeting = function (a) {
return function (b) {
    return a + ' ' + b
    }
}

let hello = greeting('Hello')
let morning = greeting('Good morning')

hello('Austin') // returns Hello Austin
hello('Roy') // returns Hello Roy
morning('Austin') // returns Good morning Austin
morning('Roy') //returns Good Morning Roy
```

Answer (score 0):

`()` indicates an empty arguments list.

`drawer` is a function that takes one argument (`open`). The return value is *another* function (which takes no arguments).